# Hiding Node app port numbers on one domain with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, reverse

I'm still a relative beginner in nginx and hope to get some help and clarification on something I'm working on.

So say I have 2 Node apps, **app1** and **app2**.

I have a production server, but I'm trying to test this locally first.

Currently **app1** listens on port 8000 and **app2** listens on port 8001.

So currently, they are sitting at `localhost:8000` and `localhost:8001`, and would accessed in the production server as `production.example.com:8000` and `production.server.com:8001`.

My question is, how can I hide the port numbers and assign them to a specific URL?

I want the result to be accessible from `localhost/app1` and `localhost/app2`, and `production.example.com/app1` and `production.server.com/app2` in the production server.

I don't know what I'm getting wrong in the `nginx.conf`, so I hope someone can help me on this issue. These apps all have HTML forms, so I need them to post to `production.example.com/app1` or something like `production.example.com/app2/download`. Their CSS breaks as well due to the location of the public folder in each app, since they are only in `/public/css.css`, not in `app2/public/css.css`.

I can change all of the form actions and router gets/posts, as well as the stylesheet references by adding `/app1` and `/app2` respectively in the Node apps, but that feels like I'm doing something wrong, as I shouldn't change any of my router info.

Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

Edit: So this is what I have right now:

```
server {
        # ...

        location /app1 {
                rewrite ^/app1$ / break;
                rewrite ^/app1/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

        location /app2 {
                rewrite ^/app2$ / break;
                rewrite ^/app2/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        }
}
```

And I still get the same issue where the node apps themselves are not using their contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have this same configuration with like 4-5 microservices. Here is the configuration that I use.

```
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    location /ifttt {
        rewrite ^/ifttt$ / break;
        rewrite ^/ifttt/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    location /actions {
        rewrite ^/actions$ / break;
        rewrite ^/actions/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
    location /events {
        rewrite ^/events$ / break;
        rewrite ^/events/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5050;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

Hope it serves as a constructive reference. Let's take one,

```
location /actions {
    rewrite ^/actions$ / break;
    rewrite ^/actions/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

So, the first rewrite matches only `localhost/actions` and forwards it to `http://127.0.0.1:5000`
The second one matches `localhost/actions/<anything>` and forwards it to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/<anything>`

I think you're missing the slash (`/`) before the regex match.

**Edit:**

Using Your comment as reference

The index is at `/app1/index`
a page is at `/app1/index/flashfireblast`
and the navbar header needs to reference `/app1/stylesheets/css.css`

So, To address `/app1/stylesheets/css.css` from `/app1/index/flashfireblast` you need to add `../stylesheets/css.css` as the stylesheet href.

**For reference:**
If current directory is `/var/www`
**1)**  `/`: means Root. `/`
**2)** `./`: means Current Directory. `/var/www`
**3)** `../`: means Previous directory. `/var/`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have what you suggested but I still have the issue of the node apps not knowing their context. For example, in app2, it's just a webform and posts to itself. However, the context in the router is "/", and the HTML formaction is "/". However, the current url is localhost/app2 and the new formaction should be "/app2/". I think the router doesn't need to be changed but the HTML forms do. Is there any other way around it?

Comment: if you think about it if it posts to '/' then it is essentially posting to `localhost`. So, the easier way should be using it's own url or using the absolute url or just add `.` before the `/` to make it `./` which means current path

Comment: How do I reference the / before it? The index is ```/app1/index```, and there's a page for ```/app1/index/flashfireblast```, and the navbar header references ```./stylesheets/css.css```, which is ```/app1/index/flashfireblast/stylesheets/css.css```, which does not exist. The stylesheets and clients-side Javascript is at ```/stylesheets/css.css```, etc. How to I reference ```/app1/stylesheets/css.css``` from ```/app1/index/flashfireblast``` without hardcoding the URL? I want to be able to test it locally without changing anything hardcoded.

Comment: I had to rewrite a lot of those but I got them to work, thanks for the advice.